# Trying to write a logic to use browser back button click but inside $on not able to find 'this'

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to go back to the previous page using angularJS when browser back button is clicked as it is not happening by default. I have written the below code and it is throwing an error.

```
something() {
    this.scope.$on("$locationChangeStart",function(){
       this.scope.transferTo('dashboard')
        //$window.history.back();
    });
}
```

I am calling something function in `$onInit`.

Error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'scope' of null (getting this error 4 times)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic `this` binding issue.

Replace `function(){}` with `() => {}` or assign `this` to a variable, like `let self = this`.